# Retrieve published message without routing elsewhere/after sending message in Angular

Tags: angular, pubnub

I'd implemented PubNub in angular, I can send and receive a message.
But I'm facing challenges below.

After sending a message, I cannot get a message in `fetchMessage` method. I've to route somewhere else.
I tried to add a listener and subscribed to a channel but it did not work as expected.

below is a code snippet that I implemented:

```js
// publish new message

this.pubnub.publish(
      {
        channel: this.currentRoom, // Channel Name
        message: {
          body: this.message ? this.message : null,
          sender: this.sender,
          reciever: this.reciever,
          id: this.currentUserId
        },
        storeInHistory: true,
      },
      function (status, response) {
        if (status.error) {
          console.log(status);
        }
      }
    );

// fetch message method

    this.pubnub.fetchMessages(
      {
        channels: [this.currentRoom],
        count: 100
      },
      (status, response) => {
        // handle response
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are trying to fetch messages using history instead of adding a listener and subscribing to the channel in that case? Most of the time your PubNub logic should look something along the lines of:

```js
    // setup a listener for new messages and subscribe

    this.pubnub.addListener({
      message: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
      }
    });
    
    this.pubnub.subscribe({
      channels: [this.currentRoom] 
    });
    
    
    // publish new message

    this.pubnub.publish(
      {
        channel: this.currentRoom, // Channel Name
        message: {
          body: this.message ? this.message : null,
          sender: this.sender,
          reciever: this.reciever,
          id: this.currentUserId
        },
        storeInHistory: true,
      },
      function (status, response) {
        if (status.error) {
          console.log(status);
        }
      }
    );
```

The reason for `fetchMessages` not returning your newly added message is that it takes some time to propagate it on the storage servers. And in case of your code snippet the history call takes place even before the message is really published, you can observe that by logging the response in your `publish` callback. In general the `addListener`/`subscribe` combo should be used if you want to access your new messages immediately, `fetchMessages` is designed mostly for use cases related to batch operations.

Comment: Agree with your analysis. I believe Akash is just trying to prove that the message was store. But as you stated, "newly added message is that it takes some time to propagate it on the storage servers", this is an _eventual consistency_ challenge with distributed persistent systems. While pub/sub is realtime (< 1/4s), the storage of messages is "near realtime" in that it can take up to a second to propagate to the storage servers. This means that putting the `fetchMessages` call in the `message` callback (where the subscribe receives messages) may also fail to find the message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to fetch the new message in the block where u get the confirmation the message was sent and see if it works.

Comment: Yes i subscribed in that confirmation box.

Comment: No, this is not reliable, as per my comment to @salet answer above.  Here is that comment: @salet said, "newly added message is that it takes some time to propagate it on the storage servers", this is an eventual consistency challenge with distributed persistent systems. While pub/sub is realtime (< 1/4s), the storage of messages is "near realtime" in that it can take up to a second to propagate to the storage servers. This means that putting the `fetchMessages` call in the `message` callback (where the subscribe receives messages) may also fail to find the message.

Answer (score 0):

## Distributed System Eventual Consistency

@salet's answer above hits on the real challenge with distributed systems and storage. @salet said

> ...newly added message is that it takes some time to propagate it on
> the storage servers...

This is an eventual consistency challenge with distributed persistent systems. While pub/sub is realtime (< 1/4s), the storage of messages is "near realtime" in that it can take up to a second to propagate to the storage servers.

**I would ask, "What are you attempting to do?". Is this just a "did the message persist" test or are you planning to implement this in your app. If the former, see below, but if the latter, DO NOT do that.**

If you just want to prove that the message was stored, you can put a "delay" (`setTimeout`) in the `message` callback before fetching the message, BUT DO NOT DO THIS IN A PRODUCTION APP as it is not reliable nor best practices.

```js
this.pubnub.addListener({
  message: function(message) {
    console.log(message);

    setTimeout(
      function(){ 
        this.pubnub.fetchMessages(
          {
            channels: [this.currentRoom],
            count: 1 // just get the last message
          },
          (status, response) => {
            console.log(status, response);
          }
        );
      },
      2000
    );
  }
});

this.pubnub.subscribe({
  channels: [this.currentRoom] 
});

this.pubnub.publish(
  {
    channel: this.currentRoom,
    message: {
      body: this.message ? this.message : null,
      sender: this.sender,
      reciever: this.reciever,
      id: this.currentUserId
    },
    storeInHistory: true,
  },
  function (status, response) {
    if (status.error) {
      console.log(status);
    }
  }
);
```

I repeat, this is not best practices code, it is just a "prove the last message published (and received by this subscriber) was persisted". And if there are any additional latencies involved in the storage of the message, it could still fail to find the message, but very unlikely after 2s. Or you could receive multiple messages at once and the `count: 1` would not work properly, but again, this is for a simple test where publishing messages (and receiving them) is at a "slow" rate.

If you have further questions, I would encourage you to reach out to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com).